# CRM 2011 - Updated to Rollup 12, CRM still thinks it is on older Database Version?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, rollup

So I recently updated our test environment to Rollup 12 and all went well, when I check deployment manager, the version for both the Organizations and the Servers is version is 5.0.9690.3236. I also have restarted the whole server twice now.

However, when I try to import an managed solution, which only works with Rollup 8 or above, I am getting the following error message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h0zU.png]

And this is how my Deployment Manager looks:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRnn9.png]

This is another link
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5C9N.png]

Comment: When you exported the managed solution, what version of CRM was it?  In other words, did you export your managed solution on a version of CRM pre Rollup 8?

Comment: Actually the solution is something I downloaded online and the website mentions that our environment needs to be on Rollup 8 or above. We are currently on 12 which should be fine. The first time I tried importing it the DB was actually on Rollup 6, then I updated to 12 and although the Deployment Manager shows the DB version to be Rollup 12, when importing the solution, CRM still believe its Rollup 6....any ideas how to "refresh" that version?